# How to Enable/Disable Textbox per row in array using checkox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

How to disable a textbox when checkbox is checked and enable it when checkbox has no check per row on a table in array.

Here is my code.

```
<tr>
<td colspan="1" width=""><?php echo $item_name;?></td> 
<td colspan=""  width="15%" ><input type="checkbox" name="check_approved[]" value="Checked"></td>
<td colspan=""  width="10%" ><input type="text" class="form-control" name="remarks[]" required></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily traverse the parents to find the child without changing what you already have in your form html.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/9cgntpzf/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // This will listen for changes on the checkbox
    $("input[name=check_approved\\[\\]]").on('change',function(){
        // This will then traverse upwards to the "tr", then find from the children
        // the corresponding "remarks" input
        var remarks =   $(this).parents('tr').find('input[name=remarks\\[\\]]');
        // This enables or disables the text box
        remarks.attr('disabled',$(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

One note, I am under the assumption that your example is one of many in a table, that is why I have given a general method to solve the problem. If you only have one instance on your page, using a unique `id` would be a more direct approach.

Answer (score 1):

Give **class** and **id** attribute to both of them, then hide show your textbox based on checked unchecked condition.

**Try below code :**

This is your html :

```
<td colspan=""  width="15%" ><input type="checkbox" class=".txtcheck" name="check_approved[]" value="Checked"></td>

<td colspan=""  width="10%" ><input type="text" class="form-control"  id="txtbox" name="remarks[]" required></td>
```

This is your js code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function valueChanged()
{
    if($('.txtcheck').is(":checked"))   
        $(".txtbox").show();
    else
        $(".txtbox").hide();
}
</script>
```